# Что происходит если в Date передать 1 параметр?

Tags: javascript, дата

Для корректного создания объекта Date требуется указывать как минимум 2 параметра - год и месяц. Если совсем не указывать параметров, будет создан объект с текущими датой и временем.
А что конкретно происходит, если передавать только 1 параметр - год?

```
console.log(new Date(2018)); //UTC+0
//Wed Dec 31 1969 12:00:02 GMT-1200 (GMT-12:00)
```

Почему отображается 31 декабря, и почему везде указываются дополнительные 2 секунды?

```
console.log(new Date(2018)); //UTC+9
//Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:02 GMT+0900 (Korean Standard Time)
```

Откуда вообще берется это число? Отсчет времени же идет от 1 января 1970 года 00:00:00...

Comment: Конструктор new Date() вызывается либо без параметров (в этом случае получаем текущее время), либо с количеством миллисекунд (тысячная доля секунды), прошедших с 1 января 1970 года UTC+0. В примере в качестве параметра указано 2018миллисекунд, т.е. примерно 2 сек. Что, собственно и видно в результате. Для (GMT-12:00) вычитаем 12 часов, для GMT+0900 добавляем 9 часов, соответственно..

Comment: А вы документацию пробовали прочитать? https://mdn.io/date